# exposed sort not defaulting to "any"

Tags: 7

[image][image]I have an exposed sort on my view by "has taxonomy term with depth".  I want it to default to "Any " but it keeps on defaulting to one of the choices.  Is there a way to make it default to Any? I dont see the option for the default choice. 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Did You checked if the exposed sort is not "required"? (there should be a checkbox that it's not mandatory field)
2. Did you checked if the "remember last chosen option" is unchecked?

   3. Did You highlighted any possible option in configuration of this sorting?

**EDIT:**

[image: Filter options list i'm talking about in 3]

I'm talking about this options list in 3. It should not be highlighted to default to ANY

**EDIT 2**

[image]

Comment: Ok, first of all i guess you mean exposed filter - not exposed sorting - correct me please if i'm not right.
Second: i have just checked and in this filter configuration You have the list of terms. Leave blank (not highlighted) for all. Otherwise, the first selected term will be the default instead of "Any".

Comment: yes to number 1 and 2 I dont know what you mean by number 3

Comment: I added a picture, the option that says "Add select all/none links" is disabled , wont let me check it

Comment: Oh no - i'm talking about this certaing filter field (first column in Views below FILTER CRITERIA label).  :)

Comment: Hi I dont know what yo mean by that first column in views before the filter criteria label.  there is no column before that

Comment: I added a picture of how i set up the choices .. I dont see any way to make it defautl to "any"

Comment: "Below" -> i added an image for You :)

Comment: ok, great - not You have to deselect all options in "Select terms from vocabulary Event Type"

Comment: BTW. You can deselect options by clicking them while holding CTRL

Comment: If I deselect all of the options I can no longer see the query string that says ?tid=   and I need that .